# Additional duplicates not showing up in sidebar as linked question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions, linked-questions, dupehammer

If a question has been closed as a duplicate of multiple other questions (with the [new multi-dupe feature](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/164356)), only the first (original) dupe target shows up in the sidebar's linked questions list:

[image]

Neither do the dupe targets have a backlink to the closed question, which they usually do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to this dissertation on the topic: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Hmm.. that took at least 45 minutes, compared to the original dupe which appeared almost instantly.

Comment: Flagged as NAA, definitely a link only answer here. <insert holy war>

Comment: Guessing that closing flushes the cache, @Floern.

Comment: @enderland: Fortunately, the information at that link will always be cached for later use and will never become unavailable!